# ZSH how to glob non-symlink files inside symlink directories

Tags: zsh, glob, symlink, oh-my-zsh

How to glob `**/*.log`, where `**` could be symlinks to directories but the `.log` files are not symlinks?
I did try `**(@)/*.log` and `**/*.log(@)` without any luck.

Comment: I don't think the symlinks to the directories in between can do any harm. Did you try a simple `**/*.log`?

Comment: Yes **/*.log doesn't work :).

Comment: I didn't write  `*/.log`, which indeed wouldn't make sense. But I see from the correct answe by Gairfowl, why my suggestion wouldn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To follow symbolic links, you need yet another asterisk:

```
***/*.log
```

Look for the Recursive Globbing section in the `zshexpn` man page.

Depending on how your links are set up, you could get the same file listed multiple times in the glob results (that's probably why zsh doesn't include symbolic links in the ** pattern).

Comment: Thank you! I missed it.